# Is there anything like a life drain weapon enchantment?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

I'm looking for a weapon enchantment that will increase my health based on the amount of damage that I do, using only the Pathfinder system.

If there is nothing like that, what could accomplish the same goal?

Answer (score 2):

A [Sword of Life Stealing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/sword-of-life-stealing) gives you temporary HP every time you make a critical hit. 
If you or your allies have Raging Song,  [Bloodsong](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/bloodsong) also gives you temp HP on a crit, while under its effects. 
If you can add [Lifesurge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/lifesurge), it adds more temp HP equal to the weapon's bonus, every time you gain them from another source.

For "real" HP, a [Vampiric](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/vampiric) weapon will give you up to 12 HP per hit, but only 3 times a day.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that fits exactly.  However:

**Weapon enhancements that steal something or otherwise buff you and trigger on enemy hitting/slaying:**

[Bloodsong:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/bloodsong) Bad-- requires a skald and a limited resource and a critical hit.

[Fate-stealing:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/fate-stealing) Excellent if you are fighting hordes of hostile swashbucklers/gunslingers (Skulls and Shackles, maybe?).  Otherwise no good unless you have multiple gunslingers/swashbucklers/sleuths in the party and one of them has the Run Like Hell dare, in which case it's still quite good, but not for what you want.

[Invigorating:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/invigorating) Really, really not worth it as a combat item.

[Spell Stealing:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/spell-stealing) Pretty much amazing, especially when used to steal unique magical effects that can't normally be accessed by players.  Use in conjunction with [*Named Bullet*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/spells/namedBullet.html) may get books thrown at you.  Unfortunately for your desired fluff, it's a little hard to argue this as 'life-force' in most cases.

[Vampiric:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/vampiric) Too expensive, but otherwise ok-ish if you only fight 1 encounter a day.  Basically garbage.

Then, when your weapon enchantment options fail to wow you, it's time to turn to [Table:Estimating Magic Item Gold Piece Values](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#Table-Estimating-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values).

---

Appendix: other drain-y effects worth looking at getting, either via the Custom Magic Item Creation rules or other methods (e.g. [*Glyph of Warding*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/glyphOfWarding.html) on a weapon for spells, having/using the item for magic items, [fleshcrafting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/brew-fleshcrafting-poison-item-creation) for racial abilities, etc)

Spells:

[*Death Knell*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/deathKnell.html) yields 1d8 temporary hp, +1 CL (stacks), and +2 Strengh (enhancement, doesn't stack) when you use it to kill a creature below 0 hp.  Really, really good for evil village-razing slave-taking spellcaster types.  Less good for everybody else.

[*Vampiric Shadow Shield*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/vampiric-shadow-shield) Heals for 25% of the damage it deals.  Only deals like max 18.5 damage per hit, but self-stacks nicely.  You need to get around the 1 round/level duration, though, and it procs on enemies hitting you, not you hitting them.

[*Energy Drain*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/energy-drain)/[*Enervation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enervation) Has the fluff you want, but doesn't actually do that at all, mechanically.  Does deal 2d4/1d4 negative levels, though, which is quite nice.  Energy Drain is generally too high a spell level to be useful, but Enervation can be slotted into a Greater Glyph of Warding (or even a regular one with some work) and thus may be an appropriate choice.

[*Siphon Might*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/siphon-might) gives you up to a +11 enhancement bonus (1d6+1/2 caster levels) to Strength and cuts the target's Strength by an equal amount, plus it fits into a regular Glyph of Warding.  The only serious problem is the 1 round/level duration, but at mid levels that will be less of a problem.  This effect is probably what you want to get as a weapon enhancement for your fluff, which would cost an estimated 960,000 gp to get placed on your weapon of choice at the +11 level.

Items:

[Anvengen's Edge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/anvengen-s-edge) wishes it was the weapon you want, but it's not.  Still, you can probably discuss upgrading it into such a weapon with the glaive in-character, which should help with bullying your GM into giving you access to such a custom enchantment.

[Life-Drinker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/life-drinker) deals 2 negative levels/hit, which is awesome.  You do need immunity to negative levels to use it properly, though.

[Nine Lives Stealer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/nine-lives-stealer) Instantly kills foes on a critical hit up to nine times total, and has the fluff you want.

[The Sword of Life Stealing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/sword-of-life-stealing) Does much too little much too infrequently. Mentioned only because of its presence in another answer.

Abilities:

[Energy Drain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Energy-Drain-Su-): Classic.  Deal negative levels, get temporary hp.

[Corpse Cremation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/daemons/harbinger-daemon): Automatic disintegration on the corpses of your foes, plus swift action Death Knell.